# How to call Capacitor plugin for Google Auth

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

Hi I'm trying to use the community Capacitor Plugin within Ionic 5:-

https://github.com/CodetrixStudio/CapacitorGoogleAuth

My html looks like

```
</head>

<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="secondary">
    <ion-title>
      Capacitor testy
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <img [src]="image" *ngIf="image">
  <ion-button (click)="openBrowser()">Open Browser</ion-button>
  <ion-button (click)="takePicture()">Take Picture</ion-button>
  <ion-button (click)="glogin()">glogin</ion-button>
</ion-content>
```

and my TS

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Plugins, CameraResultType } from '@capacitor/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
const { Browser, Camera } = Plugins;
import '@codetrix-studio/capacitor-google-auth';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
 image = null;
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}


  async openBrowser(){
  await Browser.open({ url: 'https://www.neilson.co.uk/beach/greece/cosmos-beachclub' });
}

  async takePicture() {
    const image = await Camera.getPhoto({
      quality: 90,
      allowEditing: true,
      resultType: CameraResultType.Uri
    });
    console.log('image: ', image)
    this.image = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(image && image.webPath);
 }

 async glogin(){
  let auth = await Plugins.GoogleAuth.signIn();
  console.log('auth' + auth);
  }

  
}
```

But GoogleAuth.signIn();   gets a red underline in VS code   - what is meant to get passed in here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android studio, locate file android/app/src/main/java/**/**/MainActivity.java, and add the plugin to the initialization list:

```
import com.codetrixstudio.capacitor.GoogleAuth.GoogleAuth
this.init(savedInstanceState, new ArrayList<Class<? extends Plugin>>() {{
...
add(GoogleAuth.class);
...
}});
```

source: https://enappd.com/blog/google-login-in-ionic-react-capacitor-apps/122/